# CPU maxing with query timeouts after upgrade from 9.5 to 10

Tags: postgresql

My 9.5 was humming at 5% CPU before the upgrade.

After upgrading to 10, the CPU immediately started maxing out with query timeouts.

I tried setting max_parallel_workers to 1 to lower the CPU load, but still maxed out.

Any other suggestions?

**Update:**

`vacuumdb --analyze-in-stages --all` quickly brought everything back to normal.

Comment: Did you calculate statistics (particularly important after `pg_upgrade`)? Figure out which statements use the most time with `pg_stat_statements` or pgBadger. Start working on those; compare their plans with the old system.

Comment: No, I actually didn't even think to run ANALYZE on the entire db. Ill try both, good tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always run `vacuumdb --analyze-in-stages --all` immediately after an upgrade.

Using `--analyze-in-stages` will drastically speed up the stats collection required to get it back to normal.